# How to add custom button before Add to Cart form in WooCommerce Product Page | For Specific Product

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to add a custom button to pop up a window near to "add to cart" button in woocommerce. But This code blocks my "add to cart" button. I am using the Astra theme to edit and I add this code at the bottom of the "function.php" page.

```
<?php 
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'new_after_add_to_cart_btn' );
function new_after_add_to_cart_btn(){
Global $product;
if($prodcut->get_id()==123 ){
echo'<a class="button primary" href="#">Buy Now</a>';
}}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'new_after_add_to_cart_btn' );
function new_after_add_to_cart_btn(){
Global $product;
if($prodcut->get_id()=='123' ){
echo'<a class="button primary" href="#">Buy Now</a>';
}}
?>
```

user this code